# Navigation bar (Mobile view) doesn't close after click - Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, navbar, routerlink

When I click nav link on navbar it does not collapse.
Vue version 2.6.10.

```
    <template>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(route, index) in routings" :key="index">
          <router-link :to="route.url">{{route.name}}</router-link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://blog.inquest.io/" target="_blank">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="visible-xs">
          <Button v-if="!isLoggedIn" :label="loginButtonLabel" :isFilled="true" :action="goToLogin"/>
          <UserWidget v-else :email="setFirstName" :title="'administrator'" :isUserMenu="true" :action="gotoDashboard"/>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>
```

[This is the navbar what i talk about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv9pm.gif)

This is the header part of the code. When click on the hamburger icon class 'mobile-menu-wrapper visible-xs' this will change to 'mobile-menu-wrapper visible-xs expanded'. There for I think it will be change to previous class its solve the matter. Please advise me to find the issue.

```
 <template>
      <div class="header-wrapper">
        <div class="header-container container">
          <Logo/>
          <Nav class="hidden-xs" :routings="routings"/>
          <Button v-if="!isLoggedIn" class="hidden-xs" :label="isLoggedIn ? 'Console' : 'Login / Sign-up'" :isFilled="true" :action="goToLogin"/>
          <UserWidget class="hidden-xs" v-if="isLoggedIn" :email="setFirstName" :title="'administrator'" :isUserMenu="true" :action="gotoDashboard"/>
          <div class="mobile-menu-icon-wrapper visible-xs" @click="getMobileMenu">
            <i v-if="isMenuExpanded" class="mobile-menu-icon close-icon"></i>
            <i v-if="!isMenuExpanded" class="mobile-menu-icon expand-icons"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="mobile-menu-wrapper visible-xs" :class="{'expanded': isMenuExpanded}">
            <div class="menu-overlay" @click="getMobileMenu"></div>
            <Nav :routings="routings" :eventBus="eventBus" :adminDetails="adminDetails" :isLoggedIn="isLoggedIn"/>
            <div class="mobile-menu-icon-wrapper" @click="getMobileMenu">
              <i v-if="isMenuExpanded" class="mobile-menu-icon close-icon"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
```

Comment: Please, share your script tag, including the data and methods properties

Comment: The better way to share your code easily is by adding four space in your vscode files, then copy and paste it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add an onclick event in your router link to close the navigation bar, I don't see the code that you're using to open/close the nav, but you can emit an event like this:

Let's listen for the event closeNav in the parent component, by adding @closeNav in the Nav component:

```
<template>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header-container container">
      <Logo/>
      <Nav class="hidden-xs" :routings="routings"/>
      <Button v-if="!isLoggedIn" class="hidden-xs" :label="isLoggedIn ? 'Console' : 'Login / Sign-up'" :isFilled="true" :action="goToLogin"/>
      <UserWidget class="hidden-xs" v-if="isLoggedIn" :email="setFirstName" :title="'administrator'" :isUserMenu="true" :action="gotoDashboard"/>
      <div class="mobile-menu-icon-wrapper visible-xs" @click="getMobileMenu">
        <i v-if="isMenuExpanded" class="mobile-menu-icon close-icon"></i>
        <i v-if="!isMenuExpanded" class="mobile-menu-icon expand-icons"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="mobile-menu-wrapper visible-xs" :class="{'expanded': isMenuExpanded}">
        <div class="menu-overlay" @click="getMobileMenu"></div>
        
        <!-- here is part of the magic -->
        <!-- alternative one, update isMenuExpanded directly -->
        <Nav :routings="routings" :eventBus="eventBus" :adminDetails="adminDetails" :isLoggedIn="isLoggedIn" @closeNav="isMenuExpanded = false"/>

        <!-- alternative two, update isMenuExpanded using the closeNavBar method -->
        <!--<Nav :routings="routings" :eventBus="eventBus" :adminDetails="adminDetails" :isLoggedIn="isLoggedIn" @closeNav="closeNavBar"/> -->
        
        <div class="mobile-menu-icon-wrapper" @click="getMobileMenu">
          <i v-if="isMenuExpanded" class="mobile-menu-icon close-icon"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    // alternative using method
    closeNavBar() {
      this.isMenuExpanded = false;
    }
  }
  ...
}
</script>
```

The navbar component will emit the event once the user clicks on any router-link (you can add the event in any other link or button)

```
<template>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(route, index) in routings" :key="index">

          <!-- emit the event to close the navBar -->
          <!-- emit directly in the tag -->
          <router-link :to="route.url" @click="$emit('closeNav')">{{route.name}}</router-link>

          <!-- emit by using a method -->
          <!--<router-link :to="route.url" @click="closeNavBarFromChild">{{route.name}}</router-link>-->
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://blog.inquest.io/" target="_blank">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="visible-xs">
          <Button v-if="!isLoggedIn" :label="loginButtonLabel" :isFilled="true" :action="goToLogin"/>
          <UserWidget v-else :email="setFirstName" :title="'administrator'" :isUserMenu="true" :action="gotoDashboard"/>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  ...
  methods: {
    closeNavBarFromChild() {
      this.$emit('closeNav') // Emit the event that the parent is listening
    }
  }
  ...
</script>
```

I wrote two ways to use events, but they have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I use Model like you mention how I 'navBarModel ' make 'true' when click the hamburger icon? I include all the code that I use for navbar. which code you need for more clarification?

Comment: Welcome, I want to see the whole code, including the hamburger button, that way I could show you how how to make 'navBarModel' false

Comment: Your approach is perfectly fine. I think there is something small thing wrong. It doesn't trigger the method you defined. I put debugger inside the method and check. It does not hit. I will try to solve that

Comment: Could you upload your project to jsfiddle or codesandbox?

Comment: sure i will upload it and put the link here

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-cartwright-70p25?file=/src/Header.vue

Comment: I uploaded it. can you check it and provide a solution ?

Comment: Hi, I checked the codesandbox code, but you are missing some components and the router information, you're importing the header component, and passing properties to it that doesn't exist, also, importing the Logo component witch is not in the components folder or any other folder, same for userwidget, so the code is not working as supposed

Comment: I found the error. Your code is totally correct. Need to re-correct @click="$emit('closeNav')" this to @click.native="$emit('closeNav')". Thank you very much for your support. :)